# How to compress the customclaims in jwt python

Tags: python-3.x, jwt, compression, gzip, pyjwt

We are using the jwt and our custom claims have grown long and getting exceptions with ngnix server about the header size

So looking to see if we could compress the custom claims and use it (We can't remove the contents to minimize the size of jwt) we are using PyJWT https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

but it looks like it doesn't have a default implementation for compression. If we could please point us in the right direction it would be of great help